# Using "Contains" Function for Error Checking

Tags: matlab

I have a list of strings that is in a cell array called `metaData`. Let's say this array 12 rows in length. I then want to search each one of those rows and find out if the string that I am looking for is in the list and in order to achieve this I use `contains(metaData, 'myString')`. This then spits out a binary output 12 rows in length denoting where the string was (1 means string was found in row and 0 means string was not found). I would like to incorporate error checking, though. So, for example: If there is a "1" in two or more of the outputs, that would be an error. Also, if the output is all zeroes I would need to provide and error message saying the string was not found. I am having trouble figuring out how to do this, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presence of all logical zeros and more than one logical ones can be checked by [adding](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) all the elements of your binary array i.e.

```
sba = sum(binary_array);
if sba>1 
   error('more than one match');
elseif sum(binary_array)==0
   error('string was not found');
end
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!